# SQL Server MS, Tables Not Recognized, Tried All Remedies

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd appreciated some direction on this...

I have a number of tables, all in the same dB (not accidentally in "Master" or others) which are not recognized as being "valid" (resulting in red underscore and an "invalid table" warning when hovered-over).

I have tried:

1. Refreshing the intelliSense Local Cache
2. Disconnecting all queries and reconnecting
3. Terminating Management Studio and restarting
4. Ensuring that user instances are disabled
5. Etc.

Nothing works.

I have also tied creating a table via Mgmt Studio directly as opposed to using TSql, and had the same problem.

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much!

Trip

Comment: Is this causing you an issue or is it just visually unappealing?

Comment: This does not sound like an issue but a setting you need to update to not include the underlines for intelisence validation.  Do you have other applications installed like RedGate (that may be causing the underlines that you have to change a setting for).

Comment: On SQL Server Management Studio, follow menu options:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact-SQL > IntelliSense

Then on the Transact-SQL IntelliSense Settings screen related with SQL Server Management Studio intellisense support, make sure you clear the checkbox in front of Underline errors

Comment: Are they in a schema other than dbo? Is the default of the user something other than dbo? The native intellisense pretty much sucks.

Comment: For the moment it is simply visually unappealing.  However, that being said, I'm somewhat new to SQL Server and I'm not sure if I have "broken" something that will come back to bite me in the a** later.